# Ubuntu 18.04 fails to load after Gnome Display Manager

Tags: boot, 18.04, boot-repair

I updated normal system updates this morning because I have not updated for 2 weeks. After restarting the system, the boot was not started showing this error.

```
[OK] Started GNOME Display Manager.t Dispatcher Service...ed database.s.pp link was shut down....
```

so, I tried doing boot repair USB and was able to see the boot setting but when I chose previous generic recovery mode, only black scene is shown.
My laptop is old model Lenovo with AMD graphic. I used 18.04 since released day and it was fine till now.

is there a way to solve via safe mode console?
or just back up data via live CD and have to reinstall?

## Edit

thanks for suggestions. I found out that latest kernel seems to have a few problems with graphics driver from this repo ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers. So, I am using fine without it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem. It happened after I installed kernel 4.15.0-24. The easiest solution was choosing an older kernel and set it as default.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem after update on ASUS Zenbook UX3410UA, i7-8550U, Intel UHD Graphics 620. Last line is

```
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service......itrator..e ppp link was shut down....
```

Booting with kernel parameter nomodeset (with "e" in grub) did not help; reverting to a previous kernel did not help either. Fortunately I had gzip file with a backup of the system directories (/usr, /etc, etc), so I could boot from a USB drive with Ubuntu installer in "Try Ubuntu" mode" and gunzip the backup to its original location.